# Angular $http best practice loop (rollback)

Tags: angularjs, transactions, rollback, spring-transactions, http-request

I have a question about the best practice in Angular $http-posts.
In fact I collect an array with data I want to post later to my Spring Data REST-db.

But to make this, I have to iterate over the $http-post to permit all data.

Now my worry about this way is, what happens, if the db aborts the post in the middle of process, so the table-data will be inconsistent?

Years ago, as I worked in VBA, the solution for this problem was a rollback, so the whole data won't be permitted after problems in a transaction.

But how to handle this in angular?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you shouldn't be worried about the rollback from the client (angular) side.

If the operation will fail the rollback should be performed on the server side.

The client side will only receive the error response notifying the operation has failed.

Comment: But how to handle this? Maybe I'll post data 10 times in a loop.However after 7 successfully post-requests the db sends problems and aborts the process. Now my db is inconsistent so there should be a rollback for deleting the first 7 records.

Comment: I see.
Perhaps you should save the returned ID's of the successful posts and if one operation fails execute a deletion for the successful seven.

Comment: But why not send all the wanted data in a single post ?

Comment: Ok, how to make a single post?

Comment: var data = { [ 
                      data1, data2,data3 ]
}

Comment: Sorry, The last comment should have been:

You didn't post your data stricture but for example you could do it as such:

` var data = { [ data1, data2, data3 ] };`
and $https.post **data**

Comment: Ok, I'll try it next week. Thank you for your answer! But another question: How two post data in more tables because they have a relation. E.G. post a week in a week-table and seven days in a day-table. The days have the foreign key from the week. How to handle this?

Comment: Ok, I tried this: data = { [ {test:"test", ...}, { test:"test2", ...} ] } -> but with this structure I get a syntax-failure. Did you mean a different solution?